# How to share metadata of an audio url file to a WhatsApp conversation with friends

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

I am trying to send a music file from my app to WhatsApp using Apple Share sheet which is UIActivityViewController.

I am able to share the music file but the problem is I cannot add metadata to this. I mean I can share audio with url and it can be open and listen in WhatsApp but I cannot figure out how to add metadata to this url, I want to add title, description and image to my url as Apple Music do, then when shared in WhatsApp you can see some data with the file url, not only the audio file. Is It possible ?

When I open the share sheet with my code I can set metadata image, title and description in the header as you can see in the following image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymzec.jpg

This following image is when I share an audio music file from my app to WhatsApp, you can see I want to share metadata too but I cannot add these datas :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qHK9.jpg

The following image it is almost what I want, it is shared from Apple Music app to WhatsApp, you can see the metadata (image, title and some description text) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuVus.jpg

Is it possible to do the same thing as the third image in my app please ?

Here is my current code :

```
func openShareSheet(shareItem: ShareFile, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        var item: ShareItem = ShareItem(title: shareItem.title, artist: shareItem.artist, url: shareItem.url, coverImage: UIImage(named: "defaultImage"))
        
        getImage(shareItem.coverImage) { image in
            if let image = image {
                item.coverImage = image
                
                let itemToShare: [Any] = [
                    item
                ]
                
                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
                activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact]
                activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
                    if completed {
                        doSomething()
                    }
                    
                    self.deleteFile(filePath: shareItem.url)
                    completion(nil)
                }
                
                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                completion("Image error")
            }
        }
    }

import LinkPresentation

class ShareFile {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
    var url: URL
    var coverImage: String
    
    init(title: String, artist: String, url: URL, coverImage: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.url = url
        self.coverImage = coverImage
    }
}

class ShareItem: UIActivityItemProvider {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
    var url: URL
    var coverImage: UIImage?
    
    init(title: String, artist: String, url: URL, coverImage: UIImage?) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.url = url
        self.coverImage = coverImage
        super.init(placeholderItem: "")
    }
    
    override var item: Any {
        return url
    }
    
    override func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return url
    }
    
    override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return url
    }
    
    override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return title
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    override func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let metadata: LPLinkMetadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.title = title
        metadata.originalURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: artist)
        metadata.url = url
        metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: coverImage ?? UIImage())
        return metadata
    }
}
```